# How to make an array of arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Hypothetically, I have 5 string array objects:

```
String[] array1 = new String[];
String[] array2 = new String[];
String[] array3 = new String[];
String[] array4 = new String[];
String[] array5 = new String[];
```

and I want another array object to contain those 5 string array objects. How do I do it? Can I put it in another array?

Comment: Noob questions can be serious. In fact, they frequently are. :-)

Comment: Pertinent question, and answer is not obvious for who knows how the memory alignment is done. +1

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Like this:

```
String[][] arrays = { array1, array2, array3, array4, array5 };
```

or

```
String[][] arrays = new String[][] { array1, array2, array3, array4, array5 };
```

(The latter syntax can be used in assignments other than at the point of the variable declaration, whereas the shorter syntax only works with declarations.)

Comment: Could you explain further what the second syntax does? It's kind of unclear to me.

Comment: @Terence: It does the same as the first: It creates an array of string array references, initialized to the values array1, array2, array3, array4 and array5 - each of which is in itself a string array reference.

Comment: Quick question: How will I do this at run time if I have no idea how many array objects will be created?

Comment: @Terence: Can you give a more specific example? When you're specifying the initial values at compile-time, you *do* know the size. Do you mean something like `new String[10][]`?

Comment: Yes. Similar to Peter's answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet can this be helpful  in any way when trying to perform a cartesian product of a long list of api paramerters  ?

Comment: @valik: In that case I'd consider creating a class to represent "the set of parameters" instead of using an array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51161762/how-to-implement-a-cartesian-product-of-api-parameters @JonSkeet i would direct u to my question if you have an idea please comment

Comment: @Terence, you would write something like:

`String[][] arrays = { {"A", "1"}, {"B", "2"}, {"C", "3"}, {"D", "4"}, {"E", "5"} };`

Answer (score 86):

try

```
String[][] arrays = new String[5][];
```

Comment: this one is more flexiable

Comment: Shouldn't you define a fixed size on your array?

Comment: @Filip it is fixed to 5.  Setting the next level pre-allocates them but this can be changed so setting it might not be useful.

Comment: How do I insert data into the array? If its dynamic data?

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava you can set the elements individually:
`arrays[0] = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"}` or use a temp List:

<pre><code>
List<String[]> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"});
myList.add(new String[]{"d", "e", "f"});
myList.toArray(arrays);
</code></pre>

Answer (score 32):

While there are two excellent answers telling you how to do it, I feel that another answer is missing: In most cases you shouldn't do it at all.

Arrays are cumbersome, in most cases you are better off using the [Collection API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).

With Collections, you can add and remove elements and there are specialized Collections for different functionality (index-based lookup, sorting, uniqueness, FIFO-access, concurrency etc.).

While it's of course good and important to know about Arrays and their usage, in most cases using Collections makes APIs a lot more manageable (which is why new libraries like [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) hardly use Arrays at all).

So, for your scenario, I'd prefer a List of Lists, and I'd create it using Guava:

```
List<List<String>> listOfLists = Lists.newArrayList();
listOfLists.add(Lists.newArrayList("abc","def","ghi"));
listOfLists.add(Lists.newArrayList("jkl","mno","pqr"));
```

Comment: A bit more complicated than String[ ][ ], but permits more operations such as concatenating data. However, your solution does not ensure the size of the data, which can be a problem.

Comment: @Benj if necessary, it is always possible to write a List decorator that only accepts a certain number of items.

Comment: Exact, decorators/wrappers are a good way to ensure coherence. Thus, the way we are speaking about is far more complex than simple arrays. What I have done is a small utility class Array2D<T> which encapsulates some basic methods such as exixts(...) etc. I posted this below.

Answer (score 6):

there is the class I mentioned in the comment we had with Sean Patrick Floyd : I did it with a peculiar use which needs WeakReference, but you can change it by any object with ease.

Hoping this can help someone someday :)

```
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Queue;


/**
 *
 * @author leBenj
 */
public class Array2DWeakRefsBuffered<T>
{
    private final WeakReference<T>[][] _array;
    private final Queue<T> _buffer;

    private final int _width;

    private final int _height;

    private final int _bufferSize;

    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    public Array2DWeakRefsBuffered( int w , int h , int bufferSize )
    {
        _width = w;
        _height = h;
        _bufferSize = bufferSize;
        _array = new WeakReference[_width][_height];
        _buffer = new LinkedList<T>();
    }

    /**
     * Tests the existence of the encapsulated object
     * /!\ This DOES NOT ensure that the object will be available on next call !
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @return
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
     */public boolean exists( int x , int y ) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
    {
        if( x >= _width || x < 0 )
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException( "Index out of bounds (get) : [ x = " + x + "]" );
        }
        if( y >= _height || y < 0 )
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException( "Index out of bounds (get) : [ y = " + y + "]" );
        }
        if( _array[x][y] != null )
        {
            T elem = _array[x][y].get();
            if( elem != null )
            {
            return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the encapsulated object
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @return
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
     * @throws NoSuchElementException
     */
    public T get( int x , int y ) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException , NoSuchElementException
    {
        T retour = null;
        if( x >= _width || x < 0 )
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException( "Index out of bounds (get) : [ x = " + x + "]" );
        }
        if( y >= _height || y < 0 )
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException( "Index out of bounds (get) : [ y = " + y + "]" );
        }
        if( _array[x][y] != null )
        {
            retour = _array[x][y].get();
            if( retour == null )
            {
            throw new NoSuchElementException( "Dereferenced WeakReference element at [ " + x + " ; " + y + "]" );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NoSuchElementException( "No WeakReference element at [ " + x + " ; " + y + "]" );
        }
        return retour;
    }

    /**
     * Add/replace an object
     * @param o
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
     */
    public void set( T o , int x , int y ) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
    {
        if( x >= _width || x < 0 )
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException( "Index out of bounds (set) : [ x = " + x + "]" );
        }
        if( y >= _height || y < 0 )
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException( "Index out of bounds (set) : [ y = " + y + "]" );
        }
        _array[x][y] = new WeakReference<T>( o );

        // store local "visible" references : avoids deletion, works in FIFO mode
        _buffer.add( o );
        if(_buffer.size() > _bufferSize)
        {
            _buffer.poll();
        }
    }

}
```

Example of how to use it :

```
// a 5x5 array, with at most 10 elements "bufferized" -> the last 10 elements will not be taken by GC process
Array2DWeakRefsBuffered<Image> myArray = new Array2DWeakRefsBuffered<Image>(5,5,10);
Image img = myArray.set(anImage,0,0);
if(myArray.exists(3,3))
{
    System.out.println("Image at 3,3 is still in memory");
}
```

Comment: +1 for your effort, but: instead of initializing your int fields to -1 and reassigning them in the Constructor, you should make them final and assign them *only* in the Constructor.

Comment: @Sean : I modified the code (posted new one with "no-GC buffer", including your wise comment.