# How to paint only visible area of my custom control in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, invalidation

Suppose I have big custom control inscribed inside `JScrollPane` or clipped by other reasons. How to determine from within `paintComponent()` method which coordinates are to paint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), it has an excellent explanation.

But the general gist is, when your component is painted, its clipping rectangle is already set (nb need to check how this works for view ports, but I suspect its the same) to the visible area needing to be updated.

You can check the clip rectangle of the Graphics context past to your paint method and determine what area you should update.

Comment: [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11330436/714968), then I'm not sure if is there only visible rectangle painted (by default)

Answer (score 2):

You can find out the *[JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html)* [viewport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html) with

```
jScrollPane.getViewport()
```

once there you can know the rectangle shown by the *[JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html)* with

```
jScrollPane.getViewport().getViewRect()
```

so the you can you that *[Rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html)* to paint your custom component

Regards

Comment: I need my control does not know it is inside scroll pane.