# Easy way to Create a Matrix Array with Vector Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, matrix, vector

I have a couple of vectors that I want to summarize to matrix array.

```
   vector1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
   vector2 = {1, 4, 3, 6, 5}
   vector3 = {8, 2, 3, 4, 5}

   matrix [][] ={{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                 {1, 4, 3, 6, 5},
                 {8, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
```

How can I easily create such a matrix?

Comment: Which programming language is this?

Comment: @codor: oh I'm sorry. I need it for java

Comment: The question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781100/how-to-make-an-array-of-arrays-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what type your Vectors are, but I'll assume they're `Integer`s for now. Replace `Integer` with whatever type you're using if you aren't.

If you're willing to use a `Vector` instead of an `array`, you can declare matrix like:

```
Vector<Vector<Integer>> matrix = new Vector<Vector<Integer>>();
```

And you can then add the elements like

```
matrix.add(vector1);
matrix.add(vector2);
matrix.add(vector3);
```

You'll then be able to access elements like

```
matrix.get(2).get(4); //Returns 6 from the sample data
```

If you *really* want to use `arrays`, for whatever reason, it's still not hard to do, it's just another method from your vectors.

You would instead declare your `matrix` like:

```
Integer[][] matrix = {vector1.toArray(), vector2.toArray(), vector3.toArray()};
```

Then you can access elements like

```
matrix[2][4]; //Returns 6 from the sample data
```

I will note, I'm not 100% that you'd need to do `Integer[][]` instead of just `int[][]`, but I think since you can't use primitives for your `Vector`'s generic you might have to keep on using `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Integer[][] matrix = new Integer[3][5];
    **static**
        matrix[0][0] == 1;
        matrix[0][1] == 2;
        matrix[0][2] == 3;
        matrix[0][3] == 4;
        matrix[0][4] == 5;    
        matrix[1][0] == 1;
        matrix[1][0] == 4;
        matrix[1][0] == 3;
        matrix[1][0] == 6;
        matrix[1][0] == 5;
        matrix[1][0] == 8;
        matrix[1][0] == 2;
        matrix[1][0] == 3;
        matrix[1][0] == 4;
   **dynamic**
        Integer[][] matrix = {vector1.toArray(), vector2.toArray(), vector3.toArray()};
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your program will use matrix in multiple places, and after a while you will have to reinvent the wheel and write part of your own library for matrices.

You should seriously consider using [some](http://java-matrix.org/) already existing library for them.

With current approach half of your code will consist of for loops which operate on 2D (or more) arrays.