# Create array of arrays (2D) without initializing inner arrays in Java

Tags: java, c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to build a 2D array from N (one-dimensional) arrays. The only problem is, as far as I can tell, the only way to declare a multi-dimensional array in Java requires you to specify all inner dimension sizes, and those sub-arrays get created. In this case, this seems wasteful, since they will be overwritten

In C++, I could do this:

```
Object** arr = new Object*[n];

for(int i=0;i<n; ++i)
{
      arr[i] = getObjArr();
}
```

In Java, you have to say this:

```
Object[][] arr = new Object[n][0]; //inner dimension is required
```

Each of those n zero-length arrays will be created, only to get overwritten as the array is populated. Is there a way to declare a multi-dimensional array (similar to the pointer to pointer(s) syntax of C) without allocating the inner arrays?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4781111/212870 suggests you can omit the 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner dimensions do **not** have to be specified.  This is legal in Java:

```
Object[][] arr = new Object[n][];
```

This creates an array of `n` elements, where each element has type `Object[]`.  Since you did not specify an inner dimension, those `n` elements are all initialized to `null`.  You can then assign any `Object[]` you want to any of those `n` array elements.

For higher-dimensional arrays, the rule (if you don't have an initializer) is that you can say `new T` followed by one or more specified dimensions (`[some-value]`), followed by zero or more `[]` for unspecified dimensions.  You can't have `[]` followed by `[value]`.

Comment: Well I thought I had already tried that, but sure enough, it does work!

Comment: Maybe you tried `new Object[][n]`?  That's not legal.

Comment: No, I understand that Java is row-major, just like C. I think I got confused by an unrelated error.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  I don't know why you think you have to do that!

```
   double[][] foo = new double[2][];
```

is perfectly fine.  The "inner" arrays will be null.

Comment: Perhaps you're switching indexes wrt "row" vs. "column" major (for lack of a better thing to call that)?