# In which more than 1 elements are stored in an index

Tags: java

I want to store more than one elements in an index. Example I want to store 23,45,67 at index 0, 12 34 56 at index 1, and so on. How can I store?

Comment: Have you ever heard of Arrays of Arrays. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781100/how-to-make-an-array-of-arrays-in-java

Comment: but I want to build.. That's my part of home work

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 2):

May a two dimensional array will help?

```
int[][] yourArray = {{23,45,67},{0,12,34}};
```

you can access the values like this

```
yourArray[0][0]; //will be 23
yourArray[0][1]; //will be 45
yourArray[0][2]; //will be 67
yourArray[1][0]; //will be 0
yourArray[1][1]; //will be 12
yourArray[1][2]; //will be 34
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to build an ArrayList of ArrayLists, or something similar

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different ways you could try this.
One option is a 2D array, basically an array of arrays, which is discussed in detail [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781100/how-to-make-an-array-of-arrays-in-java)
The best way I can think of is using something called a Linked List, which is a data structure that does not have a set numerical order, but instead each item of data also has a variable referring to the next item of data. There's lots of information here on StackOverflow on how to implement it. By creating an array of Linked Lists, index 0 would refer to a list, that could contain as many pieces of data as you would like. It's discussed in detail [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042/how-do-i-create-a-linked-list-data-structure-in-java)
Best of luck!