# Making 2d array of views fetched from db

Tags: arrays, database

I am fetching product in cart from database like in image and using code below :-

```
    public void addToCart(final LinearLayout mycartlist)
        {

    db = new DBHandler(getApplicationContext());
    lm = new ListModel();

    cartlist.clear();

    db.open();
    cartlist = db.getAllCart();
    db.close();
    int vj;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    for (int i = 0; i < cartlist.size(); i++) {

        vj = i;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addtocartcustom, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imagecart = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Imagecart);
        holder.titlecart = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titlecart);
        holder.codecart = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.codecart);
        holder.deleteCart = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.deletecart);
        holder.pricecart = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pricecart);
        holder.minuscart = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.minuscart);
        holder.pluscart = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pluscart);
        holder.quantitycart = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.quantitycart);

        byte[] byteArray = cartlist.get(i).getImage();

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0,
                byteArray.length);

        holder.imagecart.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        holder.titlecart.setText(cartlist.get(i).getTitle());
           holder.codecart.setText(cartlist.get(i).getCode());


        double s;

        double s1;

        holder.quantitycart.setText(cartlist.get(i).getQuantity());


        s = cartlist.get(i).getPrice();


        s1 = s * Double.parseDouble(cartlist.get(i).getQuantity());
        holder.pricecart.setText(String.valueOf(s1));





        AddTocart.total(AddTocart.this, String.valueOf(s1));
```

I am fetching product id , price etc from database . 
Now what i need to do is store all views in a 2d array like :-

```
[productlist] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 560
                [quantity] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 561
                [quantity] => 2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 477
                [quantity] => 3
            )

    )
```

Please help ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an array of arrays in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781100/how-to-make-an-array-of-arrays-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

for (int j = 0; j < cartlist.size(); j++) {
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hashMap.put("product_id", "" + cartlist.get(j).getCode());
            hashMap.put("quantity", "" + cartlist.get(j).getQuantity());
            list.add(hashMap);
        }
```

Comment: If this solution helps you, please click the tick mark to the left of the answer.