# Can an array hold other arrays in java?

Tags: java, arrays

Can an array hold other arrays in java?

```
public class JavaPro {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] one = {'X', 'O', 'B'};
        char[] two = {'Y', 'R', 'T'};
        char[] three = {'R', 'F', 'Y'};

        char storeAllArray[] = {one, two, three};
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you might get a better answer if you tell us WHY you want to do this.

Comment: The question already present [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781100/how-to-make-an-array-of-arrays-in-java).

Comment: I wanna make a game that gives randomly letters and prompt to user the  word in order