# Array in an Array

Tags: java

I want to know if it possible to handle an array in another array, i never heard of something like that and i'm curious if it is possible, because i'm writing a little programm rigth now and i would need something like this!
An example(maybe this can be solved other than using an array in an array):
i have two String arrays like this:

```
public String[] stringArray1 = { "0", "1", "2", "3" }, stringArray2 = { "0", "1", "2", "3" };
```

now i would need something like this:

```
public /*type?*/[] allArrays = { stringArray1, stringArray2 };
```

because i need to access it using an for loop and i dont want to use thousands of if statements to get to the stringArrays(this is just an example in my real programm there are like 100 arrays):

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfArrays/*100*/; i+=2)
test/*a rondom void*/(allArrays[i], allArrays[i+1]);
```

in my programm there are always two arrays connected that's why i call one with i and one with i+1... so now this is how my test looks like:

```
public void test(/*type?*/ test1, /*type?*/ test2)
{
//now i need to use test1 & test2 as string to f.e. like this:
if(test1[2].contains("1"))
//do something
}
```

Comment: `String[][]`, a two dimensional array, is actually an array containing arrays.

Comment: Do you mean `String[][]`, i.e. a 2D array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[][] arrays = new String[][] { stringarray1, stringarray2, stringarray3 };
```

Comment: if you want your code to be dynamic try using arraylist ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> listoflists = new ArrayList<String>();
nodes.add(listoflists);

Comment: exactly what i've looked for! thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781100/how-to-make-an-array-of-arrays-in-java).  You need an array of arrays.

```
public String[][] allArrays = { stringArray1, stringArray2 };
```

Comment: You admit it's a duplicate, so why answer and not just mark as dup?

Comment: @Idos I don't think I have enough SO reputation to mark it as duplicate.

Comment: flag as duplicate :) (I didn't downvote, just to be clear)

Comment: @Idos I just did, thank you :)