# How do I allocate an array of arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, allocation

I want to dynamically allocate memory for an array of arrays, knowing that the number of rows is going to be n, but I don't want to allocate more memory for each row than needed, which is going to be i = 1:n, number of elements = i for each row, and I know this in advance.

```
    int [] a = new int[n];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
```

I have just started to learn Java, and I'm new to this.
As far as I know, the first line will allocate memory for n elements (number of rows), and what I want to do is create a new array of i elements at each iteration.

Comment: You should prefer using ArrayList if you need dynamism in size, although arrays perform better than ArrayList

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an array of arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781100/how-to-make-an-array-of-arrays-in-java)

Comment: I'd checked that before posting the question, it's not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare a two-dimensional array and allocate the first dimensional

```
  int [][] a = new int[n][];
```

And then, inside a loop, you can allocate the second one

```
 for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
   a[i] = new int[necessary_length];
```

But if you know the size in advance you obviously can declare it in the beginning

```
  int [][] a = new int[n][n];
```